# Numerical Problems with cancellation in C++

Tags: c++, mpi, numeric, floating-accuracy, cancellation

I do have a problem with cancellation in floating point arithmetic. I know where the problem lies, but I can't think of an efficient solution.

Here is my problem: I have a particle simulation in 3D, so each particle has 3 coordinates (x, y, z). The whole domain is split into subcells. At one point I calculate the ID of the subcell in which  the particle is at a timestep. This is a simple formula:

```
   int cellOffset_y = (pos[1] - y_min) / cellWidth_y;
```

pos[1] is the x-coordinate of the particle, y_min is the beginning of the domain and cellWidth the width of a cell.

Here's my problem: I have a testcase in which case the coordinates of the particle should be 0. Due to floating point inaccuracy, it is approx. -3e-18. When I use this formula, the -3e-18 drops due to cancellation. The big problem here is now that, since the particle position is negative, and the border is exactly at 0, I get a different cellID returned than in which the particle is really in.

So does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? I hope it is stated clearly

Comment: Can't you just compare with a tolerance? (such as epsilon).

Comment: Also in your fragment, `cellOffset_y` is an int, e-18 will just be 0.

Comment: @111111: I think it's `pos` that's -3e-18...

Comment: Yeah, cellOffset_y is supposed to be an int, as it is the ID of the cell in y-direction. pos[1] in my example was the -3e-18, yes

Comment: Well, you need to set for yourself how much error in pos[1] is acceptable to you and accordingly set that as 0. for e.g. anything from the range -1e-15 - 1e-14 can be safely considered as a zero

Comment: With approximate coordinates you get approximate cell ID, especially if the particle is on the very border between two cells. This is perfectly normal in particle methods. I don't see the problem here (and I myself do particle simulations for quite some time) and I would blame your test case.

Comment: I don't see a problem--just make sure you clamp the result in [0, numCells-1] after you compute it.

Comment: The problem here is that it is a parallel simulation. As long as I'm playing around on one processor it wasn't a problem, but when this border is a boundary between processors and the particle has to be exchanged, it crashes with multiple threads

Comment: @Chris: Then it sounds like you either need an unambiguously-robust way of performing the upstream calculation, or to find a way to make your exchange mechanism tolerant of this kind of pathological case.

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two choices (well, three, if you count "live with the problem" as a valid choice!):

1. Shift the borders in your grid by a small amount, in order to allow for some level of upstream inaccuracy.  So the calculation would become `(pos - y_min + k) / width`, for some small value of `k`.

   Of course, this doesn't cope with errors that occur in the other direction (i.e. numbers that are slightly too big); in fact, this makes that situation worse.  But there is no general way to fix this problem; your code cannot "know" whether -3e-18 is correct or just slightly wrong!
2. Fix the upstream calculation.

Comment: 1. has got the problem you mentioned, it'll only work in one direction and the upstream calculation is basically a given formula (I use the velocity-strömer-verlet algorithm). 3rd way would be to check after the calculation if the boundaries are correct, but this would need an additional 6 checks for each particle and I'm interested in performance ...

Comment: @Chris: Indeed.  So it's really not a good solution, unless you know, for instance, that the upstream calculation is biased.

Comment: @Chris: Sure, if you have some alternate mechanism for verifying correctness, then you can use that (but presumably this doesn't tell you what the correct answer is in the case of error, otherwise you'd just use this mechanism in the first place?).  But in the general case, there is no way to know that an input is wrong.